# Sql query in django. How to translate?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have this SQL query:

```
"INSERT INTO $TABLENAME (address, count) VALUES(%s, %s) \
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = VALUES(count) + count"
```

How to translate it into django ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `get_or_create` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Fore example lets assume $TABLENAME is represented by a django model called MyModel:

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py:

```
new_model, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(address="123 1st st")
new_model.count += 1
new_model.save()
```

get_or_create will either create a new object with the given properties or if it already exists it will return the existing object which you can then update.